# Can I use Anypoint Studio 6.0 and 7 at the same time?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

We have projects going on and we are developing on AS 6 and I want to test AS 7.0 without breaking the 6 version. Can I run them at the same time? If not should I uninstall 7.0 version and install 6 again when I am done with 7.0 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

more than Anypoint studio, I would care about which version of mule runtime you are using.

in the latest anypoint version 6.x there is mule runtime 3.9.0

in the latest one for 7. there is mule runtime 4.1.1.

you can install previous mule runtime version from the menu (install new software and add this url: http://studio.mulesoft.org/r5/studio-runtimes/)

Answer (score 0):

- If you are on Windows, you can go simply install into two separate folders.
- If you are on Linux, I suggest you have two separate installations of eclipse (just unzip eclipse into two separate folders) and install the studio versions as plugins, for example, see [this](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-studio/v/6/studio-in-eclipse) from MuleSoft documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have both Anypoint Studio 6 and 7 installed on your PC. They should be in separate install folders. Make sure the Anypoint Studio 7 points to JDK 1.8 or higher version.